# Script in autoload is not running

Tags: neovim, vimscript

I'm using Linux, Vim (nox) 9.0, and Neovim 0.9.4; I have both environments synchronized.

What would prevent a `.vim` file in `~/.vim/autoload/` or `~/.config/nvim/autoload/` from autoloading?

The only script that's autoloading for me is `plug.vim`  None of my custom scripts are loading. I get no errors.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? If one answer address your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script in `autoload` is loaded when a function that is defined in your `autoload` script is called.

The `autoload` scripts have been introduced to optimize the Vim startup time. Instead of loading all the Vim scripts to make all the plugin functions available some Vim scripts loading are postponed to the moment a function that is defined in it is called.

Suppose you have a file: `~/.vim/autoload/foo.vim` with the following content:

```
function! foo#bar()
  echom 'foo#bar()'
endfunction
```

The script `autoload/foo.vim` will only be loaded when another scripts or `call` command calls `foo#bar()`

```
:call foo#bar()
```

More information with: `:help autoload`

Remark: If you want your script to be sourced at startup unconditionally you can put it in the `plugin` folder.

More information with `:help standard-plugin`

Comment: Ok. It makes sense. My two scripts define some functions but also contain the keybindings. Since the keybindings live in the script file, and the script file isn't run until a function therein is used, that would explain why my scripts aren't working. They're never loaded and the bindings are never defined. I suppose the simple solution is to `source` the two scripts in my RC.

Comment: If you want a script to be sourced you could put it in the `plugin` folder. I would put the keybinding in a `plugin` script and the functions in the `autoload` script. Like this the `autoload` script is loaded only when the keymappings are first used and don't slow down the Vim startup :-)

Comment: Does nvim acknowledge the `plugin` folder? And if so, does it **truly** automatically source files there? (Or will I still need a `source ...` line in my rc/init files?)

Comment: It does but and you don't need the explicitly source it's content more information with `:help standard-plugin`